# TimeFence.inInterval in Awareness API not working

Tags: android, google-awareness

I am using this to set up a time fence:

```
ArrayList<AwarenessFence> awarenessFences = new ArrayList<AwarenessFence();
awarenessFences.add(TimeFence.inInterval(timeInMillis, timeInMillis+5L));
AwarenessFence customFence = AwarenessFence.and(awarenessFences);
```

However, the fence is not triggered when the time falls between timeMillis and timeMillis+5L.
My receivers are working properly since all other fences are working as expected.
What can be the problem behind the TimeFence not working?

Answer (score 1):

The question does not have sufficient information to pinpoint the potential issue. From testing, the specific time fence mentioned works as expected. I can make best-effort at pointing out some common issues.

- Looking at the documentation for [TimeFence.inInterval](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/TimeFence.html#inInterval(long,%20long)), the start and stop time millis are the number of millis since epoch. Please check that the parameters being passed are actually in millis since epoch (as opposed to in a specific timezone or since start of day)
- The interval of the timeFence is 5 milliseconds which is very short. As a practical matter, I would set the interval to something that is perceivable, perhaps a few seconds or better still, one minute.
- On the earlier point, if timeMillis is obtained from System.currentTimeMillis(), then current time plus 5 ms might have already passed by the time the fence is registered with the API. Again, this points to using a longer interval in practice.